# How to fix hermes on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have an existing react native app which even though I configure hermes in android/app/build.gradle and in proguard-rules won't work.

What I mean by won't work is that when I check at runtime, it says that hermes is not running.

```
    const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal;
    console.log('hermes: ', isHermes()); <==== logs false
```

In the logs I can see

```
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-common-debug.so: deferring to libdir
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-common-release.so: deferring to libdir
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-debug.so: deferring to libdir
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-executor-release.so: deferring to libdir
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes-inspector.so: deferring to libdir
not allowing consideration of lib/armeabi-v7a/libhermes.so: deferring to libdir
```

in proguard-rules.pro

```
# hermes
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
```

the app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

apply plugin: "com.bugsnag.android.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


//react-native-config (https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config#android-1)
project.ext.envConfigFiles = [
    dev: ".env.dev",
    staging: ".env.staging",
    beta: ".env.production",
    release: ".env.production"
]

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"
//!react-native-config

apply plugin: "com.google.firebase.firebase-perf"
import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
   // clean and rebuild if changing,
    entryFile: "index.js",
    enableHermes: true
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);
logger.warn('enableHermes: {}', enableHermes)
/**
 * Architectures to build native code for in debug.
 */
def nativeArchitectures = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeDebugArchitectures")

android {

    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

   packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'

        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages_de.properties"
        pickFirst "org/bouncycastle/x509/CertPathReviewerMessages.properties"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
         exclude "**/libjsc.so"
    }

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion 
    defaultConfig {
        applicationIdSuffix ""
        applicationId "XXX.YYY"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1038160033
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        versionName "5.8.130"
        resConfigs "fr", "FR" 
         if (nativeArchitectures) {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters nativeArchitectures.split(',')
                }
            }
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "XXX.YYY"

        //fix for codepush not being able to install downloaded package
        //https://github.com/microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/1961#issuecomment-710698621
        resValue 'string', "CODE_PUSH_APK_BUILD_TIME", String.format("\"%d\"", System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }


    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }

    bugsnag {
      uploadReactNativeMappings = true // enables upload of React Native source maps
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        //note that config name that contain 'release' will be build with DEV turned off for React Native
        //all other will have DEV set to true. Look for the Note in the android section of this page
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-deployment#android

        //!!!!! don't modify the version via versionNameSuffix, else code push will not find the version anymore

        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false", 
                                    DOMAIN:"XXX", 
                                    FIREBASE_DOMAIN:'XXX',
                                    brandTestMode:"true",
                                    BUGSNAG_KEY:"XXX"]
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            firebaseCrashlytics {
              nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }

            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"xxxx"'
        }

        dev {
            initWith debug

            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false",
                                    DOMAIN:"xxx", 
                                    FIREBASE_DOMAIN:'xxx',
                                    brandTestMode:"true",
                                    BUGSNAG_KEY:"xxxx"]

            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
             firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }

            //disable codepush in dev builds
            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '""' // '"xxxx"'
        }

        staging {
            initWith debug

            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "false",
                                    DOMAIN:"xxxco", 
                                    FIREBASE_DOMAIN:'xxxx',
                                    brandTestMode:"true",
                                    BUGSNAG_KEY:"xxxxx"]

            matchingFallbacks = ['debug']
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            firebaseCrashlytics {
              nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }

            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"xxxxx"'
        }

        beta {
            initWith release
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true", 
                                    DOMAIN:"xxx", 
                                    FIREBASE_DOMAIN:'fbxxx',
                                    brandTestMode:"false",
                                    BUGSNAG_KEY:"xxxx"]
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            shrinkResources true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
              nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }

            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"xxxx"'
        }

        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [excludeSystemAlertWindowPermission: "true", 
                                    DOMAIN:"xxxx", 
                                    FIREBASE_DOMAIN:'xxx',
                                    brandTestMode:"false",
                                    BUGSNAG_KEY:"xxxxx"]
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled false
            }

            resValue "string", "CodePushDeploymentKey", '"xxxxx"' 
        }
    }
}
    ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a':'1', 'arm64-v8a':'2', 'mips':'3', 'x86':'4', 'x86_64':'5']
// For each APK output variant, override version code of outputs based on ABI codes
// ex) 'mips' -> 3xxx
// ex) 'x86' -> 4xxx
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseVersionCode = project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
        if (baseVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = Integer.valueOf(baseVersionCode + variant.versionCode)
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta01'
    // To enable the Google Advertising ID for adjust
    // https://help.adjust.com/en/article/get-started-android-sdk#add-google-play-services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'


 implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
   implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:+") { force = true 
}

   implementation 'org.chromium:v8-android:9.93.+'

        debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

       debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
         exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:4.4.1")
implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug-apm-okhttp-interceptor:10.4.0'

    implementation ('com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.4.0') {
  exclude module: 'nativeimagefilters'
  exclude module: 'nativeimagetranscoder'
}

//   implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
      // For animated GIF support
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:18.1.2'
  // For WebP support, including animated WebP
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:2.4.0'
   
     implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:9.1.0'

     
    implementation project(':react-native-check-app-install')

   implementation "com.stripe:stripe-3ds2-android:5.3.1"
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:3.17.3'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:three-d-secure:3.17.3'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
  
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    implementation project(':tipsi-stripe')
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar' // <-- Add this line if you wish to use badge on Android

    implementation('com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.6') {
        force = true
    }

logger.warn('enableHermes 3: {}', enableHermes)
    if (enableHermes) {
logger.warn('enableHermes 4')
      def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
      debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
      releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
      implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'Ionicons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); 
applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

Answer (score -3):

Turns out that this project has V8 configured for android. Once I removed V8, the problem went away.

Comment: would be cool if you could actually described how you did that...

Comment: @AdonisK.Kakoulidis simply remove the V8 package from your package.json

Comment: @otusweb Can you elaborate a bit more? I dont see any package named V8 in our project.